# Linux Mint LMDE ffmpeg h264

Tags: c, linux, ffmpeg

I'm trying to decode H264 using libavcodec on Linux Mint LMDE.
I installed ffmpeg, libavcodec-dev and libx264-dev but the H264 codec is still not recognized by the library in my own program.

However, ffplay works fine on a h264 stream.

Here is what I do :

```
avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
```

and it returns NULL.

Why doesn't it find the codec ? What should I do to make it work ?

I'd rather not recompile libavcodec because it would mean I would have to link it statically later on in my program.

Here is the version information of ffmpeg :

> ffmpeg -version ffmpeg version 2.1.1 built on Nov 20 2013 08:04:32
>   with gcc 4.8 (Debian 4.8.2-5) configuration: --prefix=/usr
>   --extra-cflags='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-libvpx --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-avfilter --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libaacplus --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-vda --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-frei0r --enable-openssl --enable-libass --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libpulse --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mipsdspr1 --disable-mipsdspr2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libzvbi --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-vaapi --enable-libdc1394 --disable-altivec --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-vis --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu libavutil      52. 48.101 / 52. 48.101 libavcodec     55. 39.101 / 55. 39.101 libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104 libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100 libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100 libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101 libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104 libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.
>   3.100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply happened to have forgotten to call

```
avcodec_register_all();
```

So of course libavcodec wouldn't find any codec available.